# How do you prove in Coq that (e: p = p) = eq_refl?

Tags: coq

I am trying to prove this:

```
Lemma eq_eq: forall (U: Type) (p: U) (eqv: p = p), eq_refl = eqv.
```

But there just seems to be no way to do it. The problem is the type `p = p` being an equality on the same term, and then trying to match its instance. If this were not the case, it is easy enough to prove that a term of a type with a single constructor is equal to that constructor.

```
Lemma eq_tt: forall (U: Type) (x: unit), tt = x.
Proof
  fun (U: Type) (x: unit) =>
    match x as x'
      return tt = x'
      with tt => eq_refl
    end.
```

But when you try the same strategy on my problem, it fails.

```
Lemma eq_eq: forall (U: Type) (p: U) (eqv: p = p), eq_refl = eqv.
Proof
  fun (U: Type) (p: U) (eqv: p = p) =>
    match eqv as e
      in _ = p'
      return eq_refl = e
      with eq_refl => eq_refl
    end.
```

This fails with *The term "e" has type "p = p'" while it is expected to have type "p = p" (cannot unify "p'" and "p").*

The problem is that the `return` clause here translates internally to a predicate function something like this:

```
fun (p': U) (e: p = p') =>
  eq_refl = e
```

which fails to typecheck because we have now lost the constraint between the 2 terms in `e`'s equality and `eq_refl` requires that constraint.

Is there any way around this problem? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed lemma is precisely the statement of [*uniqueness of identity proofs* (UIP)](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+UIP). It was first proven that the negation of UIP is consistent in MLTT with [Hofmann and Streicher's groupoid model](https://www.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/mitarbeiter/martin-hofmann/pdfs/agroupoidinterpretationoftypetheroy.pdf) (pdf link). In this model, types are interpreted as groupoids, where the identity type `x = y` is the set of morphisms from `x` to `y` in the groupoid. In this model, there can be more than one distinct `e: x = y`.

More recently, [*homotopy type theory*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+type+theory) has embraced this point of view. Rather than mere groupoids, types are interpreted as ∞-groupoids, with not only the possibility of multiple equalities between `x` and `y`, but also possibly multiple identities between identities `p q: x = y`, etc.

Suffice to say, your lemma isn't provable without an extra axiom such as UIP mentioned above or [Axiom K](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+K+%28type+theory%29).